# How to change date from 2023-01-02T08:41:50.037Z to 2023-01-02 in javascript

Tags: javascript

here I have a question regarding dates in javascript.

I have a problem, that is, when I console the results of my coding, the date output is like this..

[image]

My expectation is, after I ask here the output will be like this =

**On 2023-01-02 there was 1 call api**

*how do you make it from scratch like this, 2023-01-02T08:41:50.037Z to 2023-01-02 ?

Thank you*

Previously I had a data.json like the following =>

```
const data = [
{
  "host": "10.4.3.121",
  "port": 53352,
  "@version": "1",
  "user": "63edd591-77b6-427b-ab85-97f5b9e21421",
  "@timestamp": "2023-01-02T08:41:50.037Z",
  "type": "production",
  "data": {
    "context": "nad/v1/getGeopoiByKelurahan",
    "status": 200,
    "level": "info",
    "params": {
      "provinsi": "DKI JAKARTA",
      "kota": "KOTA JAKARTA PUSAT",
      "category": "School",
      "kecamatan": "GAMBIR"
    },
    "price": 0,
    "scope": "Processing query",
    "message": "getPoiByKelurahan"
  },
  "score": 2
},
  ]
```

//

Then the code is like this =>

```
  const result = Object.values(data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if (acc[curr["@timestamp"]] == null) {
      acc[curr["@timestamp"]] = { message: curr.message, timestamp: curr["@timestamp"], count: 0 };
    }
    acc[curr["@timestamp"]].count++;
    return acc;
  }, {}));
  
  result.forEach(item => {
    console.log(`Pada tanggal ${item.timestamp} terjadi ${item.count}x call api`)
  });
```

Comment: `.slice(0, 10)` will do.

Comment: @Bergi where to put it, dude?

Comment: On the datestring.